# TeamViewer: Copying Thunderbird Profile Folder and Got "Aborted" Error

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, thunderbird, teamviewer

I was copying a Thunderbird Profile folder from one PC to another.  I was using TeamViewer to link up the two PCs.  The copy-and-paste was done by simply dragging the folder from a Window Explorer window on the source PC into a counterpart in the destination PC.

But repeatedly I got an "Aborted" error.  The failure points were the same.  I examined the number of files.  There are totally 268 files in the source PC but only 244 files in the destination PC.

[image]

There are no error messages, nor do I know which files failed to be copied.  Any idea how to fix this?  The destination folder path is something like:

```
C:\Users\fooUser\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird\Profiles
```

Would the problem be with permission?

The source PC is Win 7; the destination PC is Win 10.  TeamViewer is at 13.1.3629 on both PCs.

Answer (score 0):

( I am providing my own answer here. )

I found what happened.  I left Thunderbird on the source machine running and thus there is a lock placed on one of the file in the folder.  After I quite Thunderbird on the source machine, the copy was okay.